# jquery val() contains()

Tags: jquery, contains

I want to know if the textarea value contains a certain word. This is not working for me.

```
var value = $('#embedModal textarea').val();
if($(value).contains('iframe')){...
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try javascript

```
if (value.indexOf('iframe') >= 0) {
```

JQuery [contains](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) is for DOM elements, not strings.

Comment: This won't work in all IE browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @JasonFoglia That is the documentation for the array's indexOf function, not [string's indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Answer (score 4):

Try doing it like this:

```
$('#embedModal textarea:contains("iframe")').each(function() {
  //Do something
});
```

**edit**

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AdHte/)

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
$.contains( document.documentElement, document.body ); // true

var babyEl = $('div#id');
var daddyEl = $('div#ID');

if($.contains(babyEl, daddyEl)) {
    //do fun stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.....

code:

```
             <textarea rows="4" cols="9">Something iframe</textarea>
             <textarea rows="4" cols="9">Something</textarea>

               var obj=$("textarea:contains('iframe')");

                   if(obj){

                            obj.css("background-color", "red");

                         }
```

Comment: -1 because this was already suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4939095/447356) plus that `if` condition will always be true so it's pointless. jQuery selector will always return jQuery collection object, if you want to check it contains anything you should check its `length` property. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5edsr/) vs. [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/5edsr/1/).

Comment: yes, jQuery selector will always return jQuery collection object but condition will be true at that point when any textarea contain iframe key world otherwise will be false ....

Comment: No, it will never be false because jQuery collection is an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as well:

```
if($('#embedModal textarea:contains("iframe")').length > 0){
    //TODO: do stuff
}
```