# To use Jquery Contains keyword for textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to use jquery contains for textbox,I have attached the fiddle link  for your code reference,

```
<div id="txtCon">
  <input type="text" name="man-news" />

  <input type="text" name="milkman" />
  <input type="text" name="letterman2" />
  <input type="text" name="newmilk" />
    has
</div>


Script:


$('input[name*="new"]').val('has');

$('input:text:contains("has")').css("color","red");
```

Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshjayaraman/Ytsr5/2/

Comment: I think you understand wrong the contains selector,pls take a look at this :

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: Possible duplicated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939071/jquery-val-contains) <br/>
have a look  there!

Answer (score 1):

`:contains` only looks at the *content* of elements. `input` elements have no content. You have to use [`.filter()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
$('input[name*="new"]').filter(function() {
    return this.value.indexOf('has') > -1;
}).css(...);
```